# Are mass and velocity complementary

Tags: mass, velocity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Are mass and velocity complementary? I would like to know if there is a Heisenberg uncertainty relationship between the two.

[EDIT]
No answers so I thought I would expand a little.

The reason I asked the question is because I was thinking of a case where if a small object in space were bumped by a larger object, it could be difficult for the smaller object to be able to determine to what degree the momentum change from the collision was due to the rest mass of the larger object and to what degree it was due to its velocity.

I know that there are relativistic considerations, but I was thinking more along the lines of slower speeds.

I searched the web and only found someone’s statement (of mass and velocity) that one is something that you *have* and one is something that *happens*.  That seems to argue that they would be complementary similar to momentum and position.

The problem is that in the classic HUP (Heisenberg uncertainty principle) case of momentum and position as complementary pairs, momentum is mass times velocity, so they are on the *same* side of the HUP relationship, and so this seems to indicate that they are *not* complementary pairs.

I also tried a thought experiment of an equivalent mass of photons in a box, with perfect mirrored sides so the photon are continually bouncing back and forth off the inside walls.  Increasing the frequency of some of the photons in the box increases the equivalent mass of the box.  However, the photons have momentum which is a vector quantity, and you can blueshift the photons in one direction and not the other and the effect will be to change the velocity of the (photons in a box) mass.  So the same procedure of increasing the frequency of the photons in the box can both increase the mass and/or increase the velocity, making it tricky to separate the physical aspects of mass and velocity, at least as far as this thought experiment is concerned.
[/EDIT]

[EDIT 2] Maybe I asked a dumb question? Feedback on why this is a bad question (instead of silent down votes) will be helpful and I will try to improve quality of questions.
[/EDIT 2]

Comment: why would there be?  do you know where the uncertainty relation cones from w/r to momentum and position, or energy and time?

Comment: @ggcg I edited my question which hopefully addresses your questions.

Comment: As you're asking for criticism: Its because it shows very little informed awareness of physics.

Comment: Uninformed QM formalism.  What about extensions to physics or paradigm shifting theories that remove mass from the realm of a constant scalar?

Comment: @pigdog627, you made the question much better with edits.  I am not sure if you are coming from a completely ignorant place or an inquisitive theoretical place but your edited question certainly did make me think.  So, I'd vote to keep it up and give it +1 in its current state.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah "As you're asking for criticism: Its because it shows very little informed awareness of physics." Indeed,  I would not have asked the question if I had a more informed awareness of physics.

Comment: Good point, there are theoretical reasons that say why two observables are complementary. For example, another pair is energy and time. This is actually a special case that doesn't follow from the general theory since time isca privileged observable in QM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know to what degree you have formal training in physics but the answer is, in part, reflected in the web search result.

In Quantum Mechanics we attribute an operator to the kinematic quantities that may be observed by measurement.  Kinematic is the operative term.  Even in classical mechanics we say that mass, charge, etc., are all properties of the object being observed and not themselves under observation during a process.

Of course this kind of puts these quantities on special ground.  One needs experimental data to estimate the mas, charge, etc., and if the measurements have error (even due to quantum uncertainty) this will get carried over into the error estimate of these physical properties (I digress).

Momentum is the complementary variable to position.  This comes from classical mechanics.  For most ordinary system p = mv, but even in classical systems the momentum may not be proportional to velocity.  Quantum Mechanics is, in some sense, a prescription for taking a classical system and uncovering its quantum nature.  So, the basic definitions from classical mechanics are all carried over, physical properties are taken as constant, kinematic observables are turned into operators and the machinery of QM is applied using these operators.  The Heisenberg Uncertainty principle applies to pairs of complementary kinematic variables, like x and p, and there is a mathematical formula for determining the relation.  So in this sense there is no way to derive a fundamental relationship between m and x.

You mention relativity.  In relativity rest mass energy is a form of energy and there is an energy time uncertainty relation.  But the energy time uncertainty relation usually relates the observed time in a decay process to the amount of energy released/absorbed in the process.  Now you may think that an uncertainty in momentum translates to an uncertainty in energy via Einstein's energy-momentum 4-vetor.  From this you may like to infer that mass (rest energy) is uncertain.  This would be faulty logic.  When a particle moves at relativistic speeds its energy is modified from rest mass to some other expression.  We take the rest mass energy as a fixed quantity, an irreducible property of the object.  To derive a relativistic uncertainty relation one would need relativistic versions of the operators.

In all branches of physics we use the uncertainty relation to get estimates on measured quantities by manipulating relations among those quantities.  This is a very useful ad hoc trick in practice but is often used liberally (bordering on abusive) to the point of driving many theorists nuts.

The discussion so far has been from a purely non-relativistic QM perspective.  In our current paradigm many particles get their mass from another quantum field, Higgs.  The quantities associated with "mass" will inherit uncertainty from QFT derived uncertainties in various Higgs related observables (I'm being generic because it's been too long since I've done that type of work).  In this sense you could derive mass uncertainty from these other quantities.  But again this is a derived quantity and not a fundamental relation derived from a mass quantum operator.

As our knowledge of physics increases our paradigm changes and we may not even think of mass as a fundamental property of an object.

The way I'd answer your question depends on paradigm you are adopting.

1. Assume the traditional QM notion of observable and operator and ask "is there a formal uncertainty principle involving mass and position?"  I'd say certainly not.
2. Coming from an experimental point of view ask "given a process for measuring mass in an experimental set up can we derive an estimate in the uncertainty in measured mass and location based on the uncertainty principle?"  I'd say possible as long as you have sound reasoning and mathematical relationships between mass and the other measurements.  But again this would not be fundamental.
3. Given that mass is not an intrinsic property of an object and is in fact a derived quantity from a quantum field interaction (or string, or as of yet undiscovered unified theory) ask "If we know what field operator corresponds to mass can we derive a formal uncertainty relation for it?"  This answer is most certainly yes.

Answer (score 1):

Two observables have an uncertainty relationship between them when their associated hermitian operators do not commute. If the hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ have commutator $[A,B]$ then the uncertainty relation between the associated
observables is $\sigma_A \sigma_B \ge \frac{1}{2}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|$. If they do commute then $[A,B] = 0$ and $\sigma_A \sigma_B \ge 0$ which does not constrain the uncertainties.

To understand why the momentum operator and a mass operator should not commute it is helpful to think of the momentum operator as the generator of spatial translations. You should think of the $p$ commutator $[p,A]$ as shifting the operator $A$ into a reference frame that has been translated infinitesimally.

This is why $x$ and $p$ must not commute; the position operator has to change under translations to account for the change of reference frame.

Mass, on the other hand, is the same no matter how you translate your coordinate system. It is invariant under translations, and so $[p,m] = 0$, and so there is no uncertainty relation between mass and momentum.

The same argument works in a relativistic framework, though there you have to generalize the mass operator to the energy operator.